# Custom department-like structure in NetSuite

Tags: customization, netsuite

There is a need to create a custom structure in NetSuite. The structure must be as closer as possible to existing Department record type. All standard classifications are occupied, we need more classifications.

I created a custom record type with two fields: name and parent. Parent points to the record of the same type. The question is how to create a nicely formatted name like:
"Parent_of_the_parent : the_parent : child". We need to specify all parent names in record name. What is the best way to achieve this with NetSuite customization capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the previous solution by Suite Resources if there is only 3 levels to the classifications.

If you **absolutely NEED** many levels to your classifications (*like departments or class*), you can create a custom record (with inline editing disabled) and use a script to update all of the sub-classifications that change if you edit a classification.

For example, if you create a custom record with an ID = 'customrecord_classification' and you have fields (custrecord_classificationname [type=FreeFormText], custrecord_classificationparent [type=ListRecord] referring to the new custom record type, and custrecord_classificationfullname [type=FreeFormText]), then you can use/modify the following script I wrote for you below.  I tested it and it works great, but if you want to use it some error handling, logging, etc. should be added.

```
function beforeSubmit(type) {
// Make sure you turn off inline editing on the custom record type so we don't have to handle xedit events

// Get the context the record was changed and only run when the change was made in the UI
var context = nlapiGetContext();
if (context.getExecutionContext() == 'userinterface') {
    // If creating a new classification record
    if (type == 'create' ) { 
        // Get the current record fields: internal ID, custrecord_classificationname, custrecord_classificationparent
        var classificationID = nlapiGetRecordId();
        var classificationName = nlapiGetFieldValue('custrecord_classificationname');
        var parentID = nlapiGetFieldValue('custrecord_classificationparent');
        // Check if the classification has a parent specified
        var hasParent = parentID.length == 0 ? false : true;
        var classificationFullName;

        // If the classification has a parent specified lookup the parent's full name and append the new classification name to it
        if (hasParent == true) {
            var parentFullName = nlapiLookupField('customrecord_classification', parentID, 'custrecord_classificationfullname');
            classificationFullName = parentFullName + ' : ' + classificationName;
        }
        // If the classification does not have a parent then the full name is equal to the name
        else {
            classificationFullName = classificationName;
        }
        // set the classification full name on the current record
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_classificationfullname', classificationFullName);
    }
    // If editing an existing classification record
    else  if (type = 'edit') {
        var classificationID = nlapiGetRecordId();
        // get the recored before the record was edited to grab the old value for the full classification name
        var previousClassificationRecord = nlapiGetOldRecord();
        var oldClassificationFullName = previousClassificationRecord.getFieldValue('custrecord_classificationfullname');
        var classificationName = nlapiGetFieldValue('custrecord_classificationname');
        var parentID = nlapiGetFieldValue('custrecord_classificationparent');
        var hasParent = parentID.length == 0 ? false : true;
        var classificationFullName;
        if (hasParent == true) {
            var parentFullName = nlapiLookupField('customrecord_classification', parentID, 'custrecord_classificationfullname');
            classificationFullName = parentFullName + ' : ' + classificationName;
        }
        else {
            classificationFullName = classificationName;
        }
        nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_classificationfullname', classificationFullName);


        var filters = new Array();
        var columns = new Array();
        // Filter for a saved search for all classifications that have a full classification name beginning with the old classification name 
        filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter( 'custrecord_classificationfullname', null, 'startswith', oldClassificationFullName );
        // Make sure the current record is not one of the records returned
        filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter( 'internalid', null, 'noneof', classificationID );
        columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn( 'custrecord_classificationfullname' );  
        var affectedClassifications = nlapiSearchRecord( 'customrecord_classification', null, filters, columns );
        // loop through all of the classifications that need to be updated
        for ( var i = 0; affectedClassifications != null && i < affectedClassifications.length; i++ ) {
            var subClassificationToFix = affectedClassifications[i];
            var subClassificationToFixID = subClassificationToFix.getId();
            // load the sub-classification record to fix, correct it's value then re-submit it
            var subClassificationToFixRecord = nlapiLoadRecord('customrecord_classification', subClassificationToFixID);
            var subClassificationToFixOldFullName = subClassificationToFixRecord.getFieldValue('custrecord_classificationfullname');
            var subClassificationToFixNewFullName = subClassificationToFixOldFullName.replace(oldClassificationFullName, classificationFullName);
            subClassificationToFixRecord.setFieldValue('custrecord_classificationfullname', subClassificationToFixNewFullName);
            var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(subClassificationToFixRecord, false);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: for the custrecord_classificationfullname field, it's display type should be 'inline' rather than 'normal' so people don't edit it manually.  The script is also a user event script that is deployed on your new custom records.  The script was just hacked together, but obviously there would be more efficient/faster methods to do the same if any amount of time was given to think it through.

Comment: Thanks for the script. This is exactly what I need. There is only one problem with your solution. Currently, nlapiSubmitRecord does not trigger user event scripts (There is an enhancement for this, but it is still not implemented in NS). That is why your script is able to update only one level of child records. I did a few changes to make it recursive and I am fine with the results.

Comment: In my account the script updated many levels down, I can help if you like. I am intentionally making it not trigger user event scripts as the main script takes care of updating all child, grandchild, etc records.

Comment: The following filter should find all of the sub-classifications, if it's not let me know and perhaps I can take a look to see what is going on:   filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter( 'custrecord_classificationfullname', null, 'startswith', oldClassificationFullName );

Comment: I saw your other question you posted about having the full name in the dropdown.... Good question, let me think about it then I'll add to this answer.  Just as a note, you can disable the standard name field on the custom record and create your own custom name field (if you are using this with my script), I haven't tested the script using the standard name.

Comment: Yeah, actually your script updates all child records. I did changes to the search. It uses parent id instead of name, so the logic is different. I'm sorry for doubting your solution.

Comment: For the name question. I configured two custom fields name and full_name and just copy full_name to standard name. That's how it works now.

Comment: Good idea. Great to hear you're all set. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need a name (full name with parent), parent, and name (no hierarchy).

You could then fill out the Name (no hierarchy) value (Ex. Socks), specify the parent (Ex. Clothing).

You could then populate the full name field by loading the parent record and concatenating the name (no hierarchy) value.

I'm not sure if that makes sense or not, but if you notice in Netsuite they use that structure also with the name and name (no hierarchy) that you can see if you create an item saved search as an example and you should see that both of those are available on the results.

Comment: I tried to use the same approach, but faced a couple of problems. If you create a new record, you concatenate its name with a parent node. It will be good not to store value, but use a formula field instead. Consider an example, when you decide to change the parent name. If we store value in child, we have to go to child and update the full name. It is not convenient. So I decided to go with formula fields. But when I use formula field (full name), I cannot refer to parent's full name. Formula field is not able to refer to another formula field. I cannot construct full name with it.

Comment: Is the classification for items only or for several different record types?

Comment: If this doesn't change very much is it possible with a custom List? (Ex. Retail, Retail : Clothing, Retail : Clothing : Socks, Retail : Clothing : Shirts, etc.)?  Hmm, no on second thought that won't be good. Let met think about it.

Comment: The classification is for employee record type only. Custom list is possible solution, but I would like to consider other opportunities. The structure may change frequently.

Comment: How about using my initial suggestion, then just have a user event perform a saved search and recursively update the names of the related classifications, could that work?

Answer (score 0):

It's only 3 levels deep? Or more?

If 3, create a field on the parent that references the grandparent (store value is unchecked, use the Sourcing and Filtering tab).

On the child, you can do the same thing - reference the parent and reference to the grandparent.